# Does the JavaScript AWS S3 SDK allow connections to multiple AWS profiles in one process?

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have to implement a NodeJS app that lets the user select at runtime which of several AWS profiles to query (prod, beta, or dev). Is it possible to query multiple AWS instances within the same process by passing in separate sets of credentials programmatically? Or does the SDK only allow a single process to connect to one profile?

Comment: If you set the AWS credentials in every service instantiation (API objects), you're able to access resources from different origins.  The most important is the permissions granted to those AWS credentials.

Comment: OK- this is the NodeJS API (using Athena) so I'm assuming I could pass parameters to AWS.config.update(...) and then instantiate using new AWS.Athena(). My only concern is whether or not a second call to AWS.config.update() will affect an existing AWS.Athena instance. (Which it won't, if the instance is carrying around its own copy of the auth parameters and not just pointing at a global config.)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of this

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update(prodConfig);
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
```

do this

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3prd = new AWS.S3(prodConfig);
const s3dev = new AWS.S3(devConfig);
```